# How to match sidebar height with main content?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to match the left sidebar with the main content div which I have got working, but the issue I am finding is the sidebar gets the height while the page is loading.

The height for the sidebar is wrong, please see screenshot below:

[image]

My Jquery is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    jQuery(".left_sidebar").css('height',jQuery("#main").height());
}
});
```

I would like it to get the height of (#main) once page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a jQuery method that will fire when the page is fully loaded.

Replace your `jQuery(document).ready` with `jQuery(window).load` and you'll be good.